# topological navigation plan only in local map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had established topological_navigation stack on ROS diamondback and Ubuntu 10.04.

I start the task using following commands

$roscd topological_roadmap

$roslaunch  launch/move_base_topo_stage.launch

I can visualize the map building process in RViz.

But planning works only in current local grid. Planner is not able to generate a path to any location outside current grid. This shall not happen as mentioned in  paper [ICRA2011_Konolige_Marder-Eppstein_Marthi](http://ros.org/wiki/Papers/ICRA2011_Konolige_Marder-Eppstein_Marthi?highlight=%28PublicationCategory%29)

Any ideas what could be cause of problem??

**Update 1**
I had written following code to send MoveBaseTopoAction but it just keep on waiting for server to finish!

```
#include<ros/ros.h>
#include<actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
#include<actionlib/client/terminal_state.h>
#include<topological_nav_msgs/MoveBaseTopoAction.h>

#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int convert_char_2_int(char* st)
{
stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
 ss<<st;
 int i;
 ss >> i;
 return i;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
 ros::init(argc, argv, "topo_goal_client_node");
 actionlib::SimpleActionClient<topological_nav_msgs::MoveBaseTopoAction> ac("topo_goal_client", true);
 int goal_id =-1;
 goal_id = convert_char_2_int(argv[1]);
 ROS_INFO(" goal id to send is %i ", goal_id);
 ROS_INFO("waiting for action server to finish");
 ac.waitForServer();

 ROS_INFO("Action Server Started, sending goal");
 topological_nav_msgs::MoveBaseTopoGoal goal;
 goal.goal_node = goal_id;
 ac.sendGoal(goal);

 bool finished_before_timeout = ac.waitForResult(ros::Duration(60.0));
 if ( finished_before_timeout)
 {
    actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state= ac.getState();
    ROS_INFO("Action Finished %s", state.toString().c_str());
 }
 else 
 {
    ROS_INFO("Action did not finish before the timeout"); 
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Corresponding output on terminal. Process do not die but just keep on waiting.

```
desktop:~/desired-topo-nav-location/topo_action_client$ rosrun topo_action_client topo_goal_client 105
[ INFO] [1333481238.721762269]:  goal id to send is 105 
[ INFO] [1333481238.721859866]: waiting for action server to finish
```

Did I missed something in client ??

Also ICRA2011 paper mention that, node nearest goal is selected itself. Then why do i need to send node id as goal?? How one will handle moving to anylocation in the environment ? i.e. moving from goal node id to actual location in  grid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30447/topological-navigation-plan-only-in-local-map/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-04-08**:
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you sending goals?  The topological nav stack does not accept pose goals.  Instead, you must send the integer id of the topological roadmap node, using the move_base_topo action.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-26**:
I was sending goals using Rviz i.e. pose on topic /move_base_simple/goal. I was not aware of it. Is there anyway to visualize integer ids of topological roadmap so that I can select appropriate integer id?

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-03-29**:
If you use the 'select' tool in rviz to click on the nodes of the roadmap, each node will have a marker id.  The node id equals the marker id modulo 1000.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-29**:
I can get that for most of nodes. Some of them do not report which i believe could be because of slow machine.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-04-03**:
Hi bhaskara, I tried pushing the topological roadmap node using move_base_topo action but no success. I edited original question to include observations.